# Using left over pergo boards instead of 2x4 to mount a peg board

Tags: repair, concrete, wood, basement, flooring

I have a set of leftover pergo boards that I want to use as backing for putting up a 8’x4’ peg board. The wall I want to mount them on is concrete.

Would pergo boards arranged as in the pic behind the pegboard hold up the load instead of a set of 2x4s?  I plan to use concrete screws and will ensure that mounting is good.

Is pergo better or worse than 2x4s in taking load?
Appreciate any advice on this
thanks in advance,

Andy
[image: Pergo mock setup]

Comment: Pergo is fairly brittle, I would Use some furring strips 1/2” thick by 2” wide it will hold the screws better than the pergo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will it work? Yeah probably. Will it work well? Probably not.

When mounting pegboard, the furring strips, 2x4s, or in this case pergo really doesn't take any significant tensile load. What holds the pegboard up is the compression from the fastener pre-loading. 2x4s aren't even necessary, many pegboard kits come with a bunch of plastic spacers. All the pergo has to do is maintain the space between the wall and the pegboard, getting that compressive strength is not very demanding.

So, using your pergo, it's pretty wide, so you are sacrificing a lot of pegboard holes wherever those pergo boards are. If you really want to avoid spending any extra cash, rip the pergo down to 1.5" or 1" wide, it just needs to seperate the pegboard from the wall.

If your wall surface is flat, you don't even need any 2x4s or pergo boards, just use spacers, either plastic spacers from a kit, or just epoxy some hardware store nuts that are large enough for the concrete screws to pass through on the backside, for easy mounting. If the surface is bumpy like a stone wall, then build a frame out furring strips or 2x4s, depending on the level of unevenness.

Comment: Perfect - exactly the advice I was looking for, will cut in half to get more peg board space!

Comment: I put the peg board up using furring strips all around and on the inside spaced 2 feet apart. Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Short pieces will be weaker than using pieces that go the full width or the full height. but if each piece has a screw to the wall that will probably not matter much,

The thinner wood will also be weaker than 2x4 but, the peg board itself is fairly weak, so that difference is probably not needed.

Comment: I have a couple of short pieces as seen in the pic, but I managed to get the whole grid interlocked as a grid, just like it might go on the floor so the whole grid behaves as one rectangle

Comment: it will still flex at the joins,  but if screwed securely to the wall ti won't be able to flex much.